# Enumerate equations using chapter in report document type

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I would like include the chapter number in my equations in a report document, I've got this working code in article documents

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsbsy} %
    \usepackage{upgreek} %
    \usepackage{cancel} %
    \usepackage{mathdots} %
    \usepackage{mathrsfs} %
    \usepackage{stackrel} %
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \usepackage{chngcntr}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}



    %\counterwithin*{equation}{chapter}
    \counterwithin*{equation}{section}
    \counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\theequation{%
    %  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\else
      \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
      \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi%\fi
      \arabic{equation}
    }
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \renewcommand\theHequation{%
    %    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \theHchapter.\else
        \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \theHsubsection.\else
        \ifnum\value{section}>0 \theHsection.\fi\fi%\fi
        \arabic{equation}
      }%
    }
    \makeatother


    \begin{document}
    \raggedright
    %\chapter{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \subsection{Test}
    \begin{equation}
    a = b
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But however, this uncommented code (and document type changed) doesn't work as I expected

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsbsy} %
\usepackage{upgreek} %
\usepackage{cancel} %
\usepackage{mathdots} %
\usepackage{mathrsfs} %
\usepackage{stackrel} %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}



\counterwithin*{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\else
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi\fi
  \arabic{equation}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\theHequation{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \theHchapter.\else
    \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \theHsubsection.\else
    \ifnum\value{section}>0 \theHsection.\fi\fi\fi
    \arabic{equation}
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: `article` doesn't provide `\chapter` nor a `chapter` counter... why do you want to use `\chapter` in `article`?

Comment: No, no, I want to use `\chapter` in `report` not in `article` see the different codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction of `\theequation` should be in reverse order, with the deepest level first (`\thesubsection`), up to `\thechapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\else
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\fi\fi\fi
  \arabic{equation}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\insertequation}{%
  \begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{equation}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\insertequation

\section{A section}
\insertequation

\subsection{A subsection}
\insertequation
\insertequation

\section{Another section}
\insertequation

\clearpage

\chapter{Second chapter}
\insertequation

\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{Fifth section}
\insertequation

\setcounter{subsection}{6}
\subsection{Seventh subsection}
\insertequation
\insertequation

\section{Sixth section}
\insertequation

\end{document}
```